# Maven error - Spring Surf Alfresco

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml, alfresco

To construct a project Spring Surf on Alfresco, I used the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/archetype-catalog.xml
```

I gave `groupId=surfcmistest` and `artifactId=surfcmistest-1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Then, on the folder `surfcmistest-1.0-SNAPSHOT` created by the project, I try to make build and package with Maven. I run:

```
mvn install
```

and I obtain the error:

> Failed to execute goal on project surfcmistest-1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not resolve dependencies for project surfcmistest:surfcmistest-1.0-SNAPSHOT:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.extensions.surf:spring-surf:jar:5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.extensions.surf:spring-surf:jar:5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.alfresco:alfresco-parent:pom:5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT in https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Alfresco-Artifacts has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>surfcmistest</groupId>
  <artifactId>surfcmistest-1.0-SNAPSHOT</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>sample-app Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Alfresco-Artifacts</id>
      <name>Alfresco Artifacts SNAPSHOTS</name>
      <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.extensions.surf</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-surf</artifactId>
       <version>5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.extensions.surf</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-surf-api</artifactId>
       <version>5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
         <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
          <configuration>
             <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
             <scanTargets>
                <scanTarget>src/main/webapp</scanTarget>
             </scanTargets>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

What is my error?

Comment: what maven SDK version are you using? the pom you attached doesn't show it. as it states here: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/alfresco-sdk-tutorials-amp-archetype.html you seem to be using an old on, mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.alfresco.maven.archetype:alfresco-amp-archetype
 here you'll find the catalog is no longer necessary, in your mvn command.

Comment: what I menat was: Alfresco Maven SDK, there is no sign of the version in your pom, you should have something like `<parent> ... <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent ... <version>2.1.0 ...` It looks to me you're using an old one, and you're not following the latest directives as in the link I pasted there (no need to specify a catalog for instance)

Comment: How can i see the version?

But without the catalog i cannot find the spring-surf

Comment: I put the parent but not solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you are getting is:

> resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Alfresco-Artifacts has elapsed or updates are forced

This is a very classic error and it is resolved by running Maven with the [`-U`](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) option.

You should restart from scratch and follow this procedure:

- Remove your whole m2 repository (the default location is `~/.m2/repository`) and remove any directory created by an earlier execution of the `maven-archetype-plugin`.
- Run the command:

  ```
  mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/archetype-catalog.xml
  ```

  - Choose the option `org.springframework.extensions.surf:spring-surf-archetype` (for me, it was option 1 but it can change).
  - Choose the version `5.1-SNAPSHOT`, which was option 4 for me (but again, this can change)
  - Select a groupId, an artifactId, a version, a package and confirm all those properties by pressing `Y`.
- Go into the newly created directory (it will be named after the artifactId you chose earlier) and run the following Maven command:

  ```
  mvn -U clean install
  ```

Comment: This not solved all the problem. I get: 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project surfcmistest-1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not resolve dependencies for project surfcmistest:surfcmistest-1.0-SNAPSHOT:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.extensions.surf:spring-surf:jar:5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.extensions.surf:spring-surf:jar:5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.alfresco:alfresco-parent:pom:5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT in Alfresco-Artifacts (https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/)

Comment: @PRVS see my edit, you should choose option 5.1-SNAPSHOT, not 5.1-BF-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Now, it works! :D Then, I make mvn install to build the project (I think it is the way to build the project). One more question, I want to build (mvn install?) and package the generated web application in a WAR file. How can I generate the war file?

Comment: @PRVS When invoking `mvn install`, the war file was created inside the `target` folder (at the root of the project) so you should look there. This is because the generated project has packaging `war`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your help was precious. Solved.

Comment: @PRVS Glad I could help :)

Comment: I have another problem with this: 
The Web Script /spring-surf-archetype-1.0-SNAPSHOT/service/my/body has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description: An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
 
Message: 09120000 Failed to process template webscripts/home/body.get.html.ftl
 
Any idea?

Comment: This happens when i try to make this: http://localhost:8080/spring-surf-archetype-1.0-SNAPSHOT/page/home
@Tunaki any idea?

Comment: @PRVS I suggest you create another question with the relevant info (I can't access your localhost :) ).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100064/spring-surf-alfresco-error I already created.